# AddOutParameter - non-magic number way of finding length of DBType.Int32

Tags: c#, magic-numbers

I have a magic number in the following code...

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = /* code omitted */;

db.AddOutParameter(command, "@ParamName", DbType.Int32, 8);
```

Is there a clean way to get the length of `DbType.Int32`, as required for the last argument to `AddOutParameter`?

Comment: And for ***DbType.DateTime*** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean about length. It's a 32 bit int so it's 4 bytes which can be 10 digits as described in this quote from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx) MSDN page. *An integral type representing signed 32-bit integers with values between -2147483648 and 2147483647.*

I'm not sure hat specifying the size (the `8`) for an int32 makes sense. For example, if it should map to an Oracle `Number` with a specified size of 8 it should probably be `DbType.Decimal` rather than Int32.

I'd suggest looking into just removing the 8 altogether since it's an output parameter I don't think it would affect anything.